# How to destroy views or asynchronous calls in a child fragment of a view Pager fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-viewpager, child-fragment

I have **two fragments** in a **ViewPager** while in the **first one** I have added **two more child fragments** and these two child fragments have **views and asynchronous calls** in them. Now when I swipe from one fragment of viewPager to other and then come back on the first then all views remains there in the child fragment.

I want the **child fragments' views and asynchronous calls** to be null or destroyed when swipe from first fragment of viewpager to other just to **avoid memory leaks**. Everything is working fine.

I have added two fragments in first view pager fragment like below:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.strongholdapps.scannertr.tablayout.Fragments.FirstFragment">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:name="com.strongholdapps.scannertr.tablayout.Fragments.FirstCurrencyFragment"
    android:id="@+id/firstCurrency"/>

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:name="com.strongholdapps.scannertr.tablayout.Fragments.FirstCurrencyFragment"
    android:id="@+id/secondCurrency"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What asynchronous methods are you using? You may call the stop or cancel method on your asynchronous call `onPause()` of `fragments`.

Comment: I'm using Retrofit calls. Normally I'm successfully canceling calls and destroy views in activities. But @TentenPonce how can I destroy views in the scenario that I mentioned.

Comment: Well, don't worry about leaks because you're cancelling the calls. Destroying the activities specially you're on a `ViewPager` will just slow your app because it will rebuild again the time the user goes back to it. Let the android manage it.

Comment: hmm. Sounds good. Ok I'll handover this to android, let it manage. Hope it'll not create memory leaks. Thanks @TentenPonce